# Custom .xib based CollectionView exceeding expected bounds

Tags: ios, swift

Initially I had a dense controller which contained a `delegate` and `datasource` and a number of other things related to a `CollectionView` which renders my gallery. To clean up the code a bit, I moved the `CollectionView` into a custom created view based on a `.xib`, the key point here being a lot of the numeric quantities have remained the same.

Previously, everything loaded fine, with 3 thumbnails per row. Now, however, while there are still 3 thumbnails per row, the rows overflow the right side of the screen and in fact go off screen.

My view is loaded as such:

```
@IBOutlet var gridPhotoGalleryView: UICollectionView!

// MARK: Initialization
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("GridPhotoGalleryView", owner: self, options: nil)

    gridPhotoGalleryView.frame = self.bounds
    // gridPhotoGalleryView.frame = CGRectMake(self.bounds.origin.x, self.bounds.origin.y, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width + 5, self.bounds.height)

    self.addSubview(self.gridPhotoGalleryView)

    self.gridPhotoGalleryView.delegate      = self
    self.gridPhotoGalleryView.dataSource    = self

    self.gridPhotoGalleryView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "ThumbnailCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: galleryPhotoCellIdentifier)
}
```

My issue is corrected when I replace `gridPhotoGalleryView.frame = self.bounds` with the commented line below it.

What is happening here? My guess is that this is somehow related to the `AutoLayout` constraints of the controller that loads up this view, but this hasn't been an issue in any of my other views. What's up with that seemingly arbitrary width being the magic number that makes my row of 3 thumbnail images fit perfectly on the screen?

Not sure if necessary, but here is a little more code w.r.t. the datasource.

```
let galleryThumbnailSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width / 3 - 3

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: ThumbnailCollectionViewCell =  collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(galleryPhotoCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ThumbnailCollectionViewCell

    let asset: PHAsset = photosAsset!.objectAtIndex(indexPath.item) as! PHAsset

    let retinaMultiplier: CGFloat = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
    let retinaSquare: CGSize = CGSizeMake(cell.bounds.size.width * retinaMultiplier, cell.bounds.size.height * retinaMultiplier)

    PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageForAsset(
        asset,
        targetSize: retinaSquare,
        contentMode: .AspectFill,
        options: nil,
        resultHandler: {(result, _) in cell.setThumbnailImage(result!, thumbnailSize: self.galleryThumbnailSize)})

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess is correct - on init, your topmost views have the size from your storyboard (if you're using size classes that number is probably 600x600), and subviews are sized within them based on constraints (or based on hard-coded values if you're not using autolayout). Since you're setting gridPhotoGalleryView's size once during init, it's never getting resized to fit inside its parent when layout occurs.

Here are 3 ways you can solve this problem:

1. If you are using autolayout you can skip setting the frame and use constraints in init to ensure that gridPhotoGalleryView's frame matches its superview's bounds.

   ```
   self.addSubview(self.gridPhotoGalleryView)
   self.gridPhotoGalleryView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

   let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: gridPhotoGalleryView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
   let leftConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: gridPhotoGalleryView, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
   let rightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: gridPhotoGalleryView, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
   let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: gridPhotoGalleryView, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)

   topConstraint.active = true
   leftConstraint.active = true
   rightConstraint.active = true
   bottomConstraint.active = true
   ```
2. If you're not using autolayout (or even if you are), you can use springs and struts in your init to make sure your view resizes according to its superview.

   ```
   gridPhotoGalleryView.frame = self.bounds
   gridPhotoGalleryView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
   ```
3. If for some reason neither of those work for you, you can override layoutSubviews (which will be called whenever the view's frame changes) and adjust subview frames there.

   ```
   override func layoutSubviews() {
       super.layoutSubviews()
       gridPhotoGalleryView.frame = self.bounds
   }
   ```

I think #2 makes for cleaner code in your situation, but you can achieve more complex layouts with #1 if needed.

As for what's up with your magic number - I'm guessing you needed to add 5 to screen width because there's some horizontal padding between cells in your collection view layout? Or your `sizeForCellAtIndexPath` is returning a size that's a smidge too large.

Comment: Very thorough response, this was helpful in understanding how iOS renders content